# How to get the file name from docked browser in QGIS 3x

Tags: python, qgis-plugins, qgis-3

Within QGIS 3x, there is a browser docked on the left hand side.

[image: problem explanation]

I would like to use this in a python plug-in, how can I use the highlighted file  and path within a Python Script? For instance to put into label, as in the above figure.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but how to get to the highlighted item from the folders tree? Where to find it? Maybe somebody knows plugin that uses folders or files from docked browser?

Comment: For qgis 3, look at [`QgsBrowser*`](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/master/gui/Browser/index.html).

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion @Luke . Definitely I'm rather weekend coder. I red documentation of QgsBrowserDockWidget and QgsBrowserTreeView, but couldn't find method named like name() or fileName() or something like that. On the QGIS-Developers mailing list I found QgsDataItem may help to get filename from Browser, but I failed to figure it out how to use it. I'm not quite sure if QGIS-Developers mailing list it proper place to ask a seemingly simple question :(

Comment: Further clues... look at `QgsBrowserTreeView.selectionModel().selectedIndexes()`. That's how the [browser widget](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/master/src/gui/qgsbrowserdockwidget.cpp#L380) figures out which layers are selected when adding them to the map. Then you need to use the dataitem to figure out the path I assume.

Comment: @paul did you succeed in your struggle to get the currently selected file(s)?

Comment: I wanted to do the same and haven't completely figured out the solution. But  you can get an instance of the Browser using `browser = iface.mainWindow().findChild(QDockWidget, 'Browser')` which is an object of type QgsBrowserDockWidget and then call methods for them.

Answer (score 2):

Although the question is old I give here what I could find.

```
myExplo = iface.mainWindow().findChild(QDockWidget,'Browser')
myExploTreeview = myExplo.findChild(QTreeView)
cNAme = myExploTreeview.currentIndex().data(Qt.DisplayRole)
-> expected result
```

For database

```
cNameConnexion = myExploTreeview.currentIndex().data(Qt.UserRole).split("/")[1]
```

it is then possible to find the connection by QgsSettings.